# Displaying raster data information in specific coordinates

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinates, remote-sensing, display

I am currently trying to figure out how to retrieve the information in a specific point in QGIS.

I opened a netcdf file containing information about chlorophy-a concentration in the Mediterranean Sea. I need to know the concentration for specific points, which I have the coordinates for. I am an absolute beginner with QGIS, and only need it for this single purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assuming your coordinates are in a CSV, make a `point` layer in QGIS by `Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer...`

[image]

2. Define the X and Y fields and make sure the correct Coordinate Reference System is selected.

[image]

3. In the attribute table of the new `points` layer, click this button to open the field calculator.

[image]

4. Create a new field (decimal or whole number, depending on your raster type).
5. Enter this expression to sample the raster values to the point locations:

```sql
raster_value('name of raster layer', 1, $geometry) -- `1` is the band number, $geometry is the point geometry
```

Change the name of the layer to the raster in your project and the band number to the one you wish to sample.

[image]

[image]

6. Right-click the `points` layer name and choose `Export` to save to a format of your choice.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your elaborat answer:)
Unfortunately I do not have the coordinates in a CVS. I just have the values, as I want to compare the results I hope to get from QGIS with a study. 
Is there an easy way to create a CVS with the points I need myself? Then I could use that and follow the rest of your instructions..

Comment: Making a CSV of them is very simple. You can use Excel, for example, and save your spreadsheet in CSV format. At the bare minumum, you just need an X and a Y column that contain the coordinates.

Comment: Oh awesome! Thank you, I will try and do that.