# Categorical raster values to points are incorrect near edges

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, nearest-neighbor

I have a vector point layer, and a low-res, categorical raster. The raster is a map of habitat type, and it is in the form of a single-band which ranges from 1-55 where each number is a different habitat. I want to extract the raster values to the points, so I use the "Add raster values to points tool" and I select nearest neighbor interpolation.

The problem is that there seems to be an edge effect, so that points near boundaries of habitats get incorrect values.

Example: most of the habitat is bog (value 1, blue on the image below) and shrub (value 8, pink) and the points which are near a boundary between these habitats get values like 4 and 6, rather than either 1 or 8. The highlighted point has value 4 instead of 1.

Do you have any ideas how I can solve this? Is there a way to tell QGIS that the raster has categorical values which should never be averaged? I thought the nearest neighbor interpolation was specifically for this.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't answer your question about interpolation, but you could try a different way of sampling the raster using the [Field Calculator on the points layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423955/displaying-raster-data-information-in-specific-coordinates/423976#423976), to see if it gives you a more reliable result.

Comment: you're a genius, it worked like a charm! :D thank you